# Unable to install xrdp on CentOS 7.6

Tags: centos7, xrdp

I'm a bit of a novice Linux user and I'm trying to prepare a CentOS VM through Azure.  I have it built and can operate on it through the serial console on the Azure portal.  I've installed GNOME and now I'm trying to install xrdp so I can access it through RDP.

The instructions I found said a requirement first was to first install the EPEL repo which I did this way:

`rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`

That completed with no issue.

But when I tried to actually install xrdp this way:

`yum -y install xrdp tigervnc-server`

I get errors that look like this:

`Error: Package: 1:xrdp-selinux-0.9.11-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-252.el7.1
           Installed: selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.15.noarch (@updates)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.15
           Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7.noarch (base)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-229.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.5.noarch (updates)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.5
           Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch (updates)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.6
           Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.9.noarch (updates)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.9
           Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.12.noarch (updates)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.12
Error: Package: xorgxrdp-0.2.11-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.4
           Installed: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.6.el7_6.x86_64 (@updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-5.6.el7_6
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-3.el7.x86_64 (base)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-3.el7
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-5.el7
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-5.1.el7
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.2.el7_6.x86_64 (updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-5.2.el7_6
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.3.el7_6.x86_64 (updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-5.3.el7_6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

So I research that and someone said I could resolve these dependencies by installing the following:

`rpm -Uvh http://scientificlinux.mirror.ac.za/7.6/x86_64/updates/security/selinux-policy-3.13.1-252.el7.1.noarch.rpm`

But when I do that I get another dependency error that looks like this:

`error: Failed dependencies:
        selinux-policy = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.15 is needed by (installed) selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-229.el7_6.15.noarch`

But that seems really odd because isn't the version of selinux-policy that error is saying I need the version I have installed according to my xrdp error?

Anyway, that was the brick wall on my journey.  I'm not sure what to do next.  And if I can't get xrdp installed is there another way to access the GNOME desktop of my machine?  I am a novice at both Linux and Azure and I didn't see a console option besides the serial console on the Azure portal.

Thanks.

Comment: See the linked Q&A for the reason why this is happening and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't want to install packages from other distributions which is what you did when you installed the Scientific Linux `selinux-policy-targeted` package.

You can just:

```
yum install tigervnc-server
```

After that, you can launch it with:

```
vncserver
```

Create a vnc password at the prompts and then it will show you the display that it's running on with the output of:

```
hostname:0
```

Install `vncviewer` on the machine that you're trying to connect with. Launch it and connect to it with one of the following:

```
 hostname:0
 Ipaddress:0
```

Enter your password and you're connected.

You can change the display to `:1` or `:2` or whatever it is on the VM by specifying it when connecting with `vncviewer`. The `vncserver` will continue to run on the VM until the process is stopped.